# Выплывающее меню в стиле аккордеон

Tags: javascript, css, html

Никак не получается сделать чтобы при наведении меню медленно выплывало.
Меню в `left-container`:

```css
    body {
      font: 1em PT Sans, Tahoma, Arial Black;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .head {
      width: 100%;
      height: 220px;
      box-shadow: 0 6px 6px #7f7f7f;
    }
    .logo {
      position: absolute;
      background: url(logo2.gif) no-repeat;
      top: 70px;
      width: 560px;
      height: 160px;
      background-size: cover;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .span {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 170px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      font: 1.1em Tahoma;
      color: #0082bf;
    }
    .right {
      position: absolute;
      width: 620px;
      height: 220px;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    .menu {
      padding: 0;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 20px;
      display: block;
      margin-top: 5px;
      width: 600px;
      height: 37px;
    }
    .menu a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      padding: 10px;
      font: 0.8em PT Sans;
      border-right: 2px solid #cecece;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .menu a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.8);
    }
    .menu a:last-child {
      border-right: none;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .numbers {
      margin-top: 20px;
      float: right;
      font: 1.4em Tahoma;
      width: 510px;
      margin-right: 100px;
    }
    .numbers span {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 175px;
    }
    .numbers span:nth-child(odd) {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    #search {
      padding: 6px;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      background: rgb(0, 124, 249);
      width: 247px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #form-query {
      height: 20px;
      font: 1em PT Sans;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      font: 1em PT Sans;
    }
    .down {
      margin-top: 92px;
      float: left;
      color: rgb(26, 140, 255);
      width: 100%;
      height: 70px;
      background: url(http://www.youthenergysummit.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Grass_Border_4.jpg) repeat-x;
      background-size: 450px 70px;
    }
    .container {
      width: 78.5%;
      margin: 15px 1% 0px 0px;
      border: 2px solid #007ebb;
      float: right;
    }
    .nav {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1)), color-stop(52%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)));
    }
    .nav li {
      display: block;
      font: 1.5em PT Sans;
      float: left;
      width: 24.8%;
      height: 50px;
      border-right: 2px solid #b2affa;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .nav li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    .nav li:last-child {
      border-right: none;
    }
    .nav li a:hover {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(208, 228, 247, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(115, 177, 231, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(10, 119, 213, 1)), color-stop(79%, rgba(83, 159, 225, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(135, 188, 234, 1)));
    }
    .nav li a:active {
      color: #fff;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(133, 133, 133, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1)));
      /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1) 50%, rgba(133, 133, 133, 1) 51%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 100%);
      /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    }
    .left-container {
      width: 18.5%;
      margin: 15px 0px 0px 1%;
      border: 2px solid #007ebb;
      border-right: 2px solid #007ebb;
      float: left;
    }
    .left-container .nav li {
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1)), color-stop(52%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)));
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      font: 1.5em PT Sans;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #007ebb;
      border-right: none;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
    }
    .left-container .nav:before {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      clear: both;
    }
    .left-container .nav li:hover {
      height: auto;
    }
    .left-container .nav li a {
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    .left-container .nav li a:first-child {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    .left-container .nav li:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    .left-container .nav li a:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(208, 228, 247, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(115, 177, 231, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(10, 119, 213, 1)), color-stop(79%, rgba(83, 159, 225, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(135, 188, 234, 1)));
    }
    .left-container .nav li a:active {
      color: #fff;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(133, 133, 133, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1)));
      /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1) 50%, rgba(133, 133, 133, 1) 51%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 100%);
      /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    }
    .left-container .nav li a+a {
      #2bff2b;
      #9f9f9f;
      #858585;
      #888888;
      #ffb164;
      color: #fff;
      border-top: 1px solid #007ebb;
      height: 35px;
      font: 0.8em PT Sans;
      line-height: 35px;
      background: #999999;
      #b7b7b7;
      #9f9f9f;
      #858585;
      #888888;
      #ffb164;
      /*background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(183,183,183,1)), color-stop(56%,rgba(159,159,159,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(133,133,133,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(183,183,183,1) 0%,rgba(159,159,159,1) 56%,rgba(133,133,133,1) 100%);*/
      */
    }
    .left-container .nav li a+a:hover {
      #ffb871;
      #ff9933;
      #ff8409;
      #888888;
      #ffb164;
      background: #7a7a7a;
    }
    .left-container .nav li a+a:active {
      #ffb871;
      #ff9933;
      #ff8409;
      #888888;
      #ffb164;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1)));
      /
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      .span {
        display: none;
      }
      .logo {
        position: absolute;
        background: url(logo2.gif) no-repeat;
        top: 215px;
        width: 560px;
        height: 160px;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .down {
        margin-top: 300px;
      }
      .head {
        height: 370px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Зоомагазин</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div class="head">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="span">
    Бесплатная доставка от 300 грн по Киеву и Украине*
    <br>Скидка 5% уже при первом заказе
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <a href="#">Мой кабинет</a>
      <a href="#">Доставка по Киеву</a>
      <a href="#">Доставка по Украине</a>
      <a href="#">Форум</a>
      <a href="#">Блог</a>
      <a href="#">Доска объявлений</a>
    </ul>
    <div class="numbers">
      <span>(044) 300-01-02</span><span>(099) 167-82-52</span>
      <span>(097) 081-58-08</span><span>(093) 366-30-87</span>
    </div>
    <form id="search" method="get" action="/search" target="_blank">
      <input name="q" id="form-query" value="" placeholder="поиск по сайту">
      <input type=submit value="Искать">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="down"></div>
</div>
<div class="left-container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Кошки</a>
      <a href="#">Еда</a>
      <a href="#">Заменители молока</a>
      <a href="#">Витамины</a>
      <a href="#">Уход и гигиена</a>
      <a href="#">Средства от паразитов</a>
      <a href="#">Наполнители</a>
      <a href="#">Игрушки</a>
      <a href="#">Лакомства</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Собаки</a>
      <a href="#">Еда</a>
      <a href="#">Заменители молока</a>
      <a href="#">Витамины</a>
      <a href="#">Уход и гигиена</a>
      <a href="#">Средства от паразитов</a>
      <a href="#">Наполнители</a>
      <a href="#">Игрушки</a>
      <a href="#">Лакомства</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Грызуны</a>
      <a href="#">Еда</a>
      <a href="#">Клетки</a>
      <a href="#">Витамины</a>
      <a href="#">Уход и гигиена</a>
      <a href="#">Средства от паразитов</a>
      <a href="#">Наполнители</a>
      <a href="#">Игрушки</a>
      <a href="#">Лакомства</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Рыбы</a>
      <a href="#">Корм</a>
      <a href="#">Аквариумы</a>
      <a href="#">Все для аквариумов</a>
      <a href="#">Освещение</a>
      <a href="#">Декор</a>
      <a href="#">Замороженные корма</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Птицы</a>
      <a href="#">Корм</a>
      <a href="#">Клетки</a>
      <a href="#">Витамины</a>
      <a href="#">Уход и гигиена</a>
      <a href="#">Кормушки и поилки</a>
      <a href="#">Домики</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Рептилии</a>
      <a href="#">Корм</a>
      <a href="#">Все для прудов</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Мой кабинет</a>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Корзина</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Оформить заказ</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">О нас</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: что за жуть с кучей цветов для.left-container .nav li a+a ? почти уверен, что многие браузеры вообще отбросят этот стиль

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Со скоростью сами поиграйте :)

PS: чего-то демо сюда не вставляется, так что см. тут http://jsfiddle.net/SanSYS/vd64e23r/

```css
body {
      font: 1em PT Sans, Tahoma, Arial Black;
      margin: 0;
    }
    .head {
      width: 100%;
      height: 220px;
      box-shadow: 0 6px 6px #7f7f7f;
    }
    .logo {
      position: absolute;
      background: url(logo2.gif) no-repeat;
      top: 70px;
      width: 560px;
      height: 160px;
      background-size: cover;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .span {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 170px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      font: 1.1em Tahoma;
      color: #0082bf;
    }
    .right {
      position: absolute;
      width: 620px;
      height: 220px;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    .menu {
      padding: 0;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 20px;
      display: block;
      margin-top: 5px;
      width: 600px;
      height: 37px;
    }
    .menu a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      padding: 10px;
      font: 0.8em PT Sans;
      border-right: 2px solid #cecece;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .menu a:hover {
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.8);
    }
    .menu a:last-child {
      border-right: none;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .numbers {
      margin-top: 20px;
      float: right;
      font: 1.4em Tahoma;
      width: 510px;
      margin-right: 100px;
    }
    .numbers span {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 175px;
    }
    .numbers span:nth-child(odd) {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    #search {
      padding: 6px;
      float: right;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      background: rgb(0, 124, 249);
      width: 247px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #form-query {
      height: 20px;
      font: 1em PT Sans;
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      font: 1em PT Sans;
    }
    .down {
      margin-top: 92px;
      float: left;
      color: rgb(26, 140, 255);
      width: 100%;
      height: 70px;
      background: url(http://www.youthenergysummit.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Grass_Border_4.jpg) repeat-x;
      background-size: 450px 70px;
    }
    .container {
      width: 78.5%;
      margin: 15px 1% 0px 0px;
      border: 2px solid #007ebb;
      float: right;
    }
    .nav {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 50px;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1)), color-stop(52%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)));
    }
    .nav li {
      display: block;
      font: 1.5em PT Sans;
      float: left;
      width: 24.8%;
      max-height: 50px;
      border-right: 2px solid #b2affa;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .nav li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    .nav li:last-child {
      border-right: none;
    }
    .nav li a:hover {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(208, 228, 247, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(115, 177, 231, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(10, 119, 213, 1)), color-stop(79%, rgba(83, 159, 225, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(135, 188, 234, 1)));
    }
    .nav li a:active {
      color: #fff;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(133, 133, 133, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1)));
      /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1) 50%, rgba(133, 133, 133, 1) 51%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 100%);
      /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    }
    .left-container {
      width: 18.5%;
      margin: 15px 0px 0px 1%;
      border: 2px solid #007ebb;
      border-right: 2px solid #007ebb;
      float: left;
    }
    .left-container .nav li {
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(125, 185, 232, 1)), color-stop(52%, rgba(41, 137, 216, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)));
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      font: 1.5em PT Sans;
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 50px;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #007ebb;
      border-right: none;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: max-height ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }
    .left-container .nav:before {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      content: '';
      clear: both;
    }
    .left-container .nav li:hover {
      max-height: 600px;
    }
    .left-container .nav li a {
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    .left-container .nav li a:first-child {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    .left-container .nav li:last-child {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    .left-container .nav li a:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(208, 228, 247, 1)), color-stop(24%, rgba(115, 177, 231, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(10, 119, 213, 1)), color-stop(79%, rgba(83, 159, 225, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(135, 188, 234, 1)));
    }
    .left-container .nav li a:active {
      color: #fff;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(133, 133, 133, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1)));
      /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 0%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1) 50%, rgba(133, 133, 133, 1) 51%, rgba(182, 182, 182, 1) 100%);
      /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    }
    .left-container .nav li a+a {
      #2bff2b;
      #9f9f9f;
      #858585;
      #888888;
      #ffb164;
      color: #fff;
      border-top: 1px solid #007ebb;
      height: 35px;
      font: 0.8em PT Sans;
      line-height: 35px;
      background: #999999;
      #b7b7b7;
      #9f9f9f;
      #858585;
      #888888;
      #ffb164;
      /*background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(183,183,183,1)), color-stop(56%,rgba(159,159,159,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(133,133,133,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      /*background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(183,183,183,1) 0%,rgba(159,159,159,1) 56%,rgba(133,133,133,1) 100%);*/
      */
    }
    .left-container .nav li a+a:hover {
      #ffb871;
      #ff9933;
      #ff8409;
      #888888;
      #ffb164;
      background: #7a7a7a;
    }
    .left-container .nav li a+a:active {
      #ffb871;
      #ff9933;
      #ff8409;
      #888888;
      #ffb164;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(89, 89, 89, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(76, 76, 76, 1)));
      /
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
      .span {
        display: none;
      }
      .logo {
        position: absolute;
        background: url(logo2.gif) no-repeat;
        top: 215px;
        width: 560px;
        height: 160px;
        background-size: cover;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .down {
        margin-top: 300px;
      }
      .head {
        height: 370px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="span">
    Бесплатная доставка от 300 грн по Киеву и Украине*
    <br>Скидка 5% уже при первом заказе
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <a href="#">Мой кабинет</a>
      <a href="#">Доставка по Киеву</a>
      <a href="#">Доставка по Украине</a>
      <a href="#">Форум</a>
      <a href="#">Блог</a>
      <a href="#">Доска объявлений</a>
    </ul>
    <div class="numbers">
      <span>(044) 300-01-02</span><span>(099) 167-82-52</span>
      <span>(097) 081-58-08</span><span>(093) 366-30-87</span>
    </div>
    <form id="search" method="get" action="/search" target="_blank">
      <input name="q" id="form-query" value="" placeholder="поиск по сайту">
      <input type=submit value="Искать">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="down"></div>
</div>
<div class="left-container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Кошки</a>
      <a href="#">Еда</a>
      <a href="#">Заменители молока</a>
      <a href="#">Витамины</a>
      <a href="#">Уход и гигиена</a>
      <a href="#">Средства от паразитов</a>
      <a href="#">Наполнители</a>
      <a href="#">Игрушки</a>
      <a href="#">Лакомства</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Собаки</a>
      <a href="#">Еда</a>
      <a href="#">Заменители молока</a>
      <a href="#">Витамины</a>
      <a href="#">Уход и гигиена</a>
      <a href="#">Средства от паразитов</a>
      <a href="#">Наполнители</a>
      <a href="#">Игрушки</a>
      <a href="#">Лакомства</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Грызуны</a>
      <a href="#">Еда</a>
      <a href="#">Клетки</a>
      <a href="#">Витамины</a>
      <a href="#">Уход и гигиена</a>
      <a href="#">Средства от паразитов</a>
      <a href="#">Наполнители</a>
      <a href="#">Игрушки</a>
      <a href="#">Лакомства</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Рыбы</a>
      <a href="#">Корм</a>
      <a href="#">Аквариумы</a>
      <a href="#">Все для аквариумов</a>
      <a href="#">Освещение</a>
      <a href="#">Декор</a>
      <a href="#">Замороженные корма</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Птицы</a>
      <a href="#">Корм</a>
      <a href="#">Клетки</a>
      <a href="#">Витамины</a>
      <a href="#">Уход и гигиена</a>
      <a href="#">Кормушки и поилки</a>
      <a href="#">Домики</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Рептилии</a>
      <a href="#">Корм</a>
      <a href="#">Все для прудов</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Мой кабинет</a>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Корзина</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Оформить заказ</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">О нас</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```